# What does one do at a dance without a date?

Tags: dances, social-event, teenagers

Connected to my previous question, what do you do at a dance where you know very few of the participants and you have no date?

What I ended up doing was mostly standing next to the DJ and modifying the visuals that I had created for the event and thinking about my life. I said hi to some people that I knew, but, they all had dates and I didn't want to interrupt them.

The dance was not a school dance. It was advertised as an alternative homecoming. There was loud 90s music (the dance was 90s themed), dancing, and refreshments. 
Instead of hanging out by myself and being sad in the corner by the DJ, what could I have done to be more socially active and enjoyable?

Comment: Did someone invite you to the dance, or did you hear about it some other way?

Comment: @HDE226868 I helped plan and organize it.

Comment: I realized just now how much I needed this site ! The questions are just everything I need to know

Comment: I don't really understand close votes here.

Comment: Which previous question?

Comment: What music genres did the DJ play? Only music genres meant to be danced by pairs such as [slow dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_dance)? Were some people dancing alone, and if yes about what proportion? Even partner dances like salsa are open to people dancing on their own. I would wrote an answer if the question had not been (unfairly I think) closed. The asker mentioned their goals, they wanted that evening to be "more socially active and enjoyable".

Comment: The dance was 90s themed and played hits from the 90s

Comment: @10Replies can you add the details from the comments into your question? Another issue is, was the music too loud to allow talking?

Comment: I think this question is too broad, as Joe S said. What I would do and what someone else would do depends on what you enjoy, who you want to be. I would make friends, because I can. But this question does not ask, 'how does one make friends at a party'. The question could equally be about 'How does one enjoy themselves without making friends when alone at a party'.
If the question could be edited to clarify what the OP is looking to get out of the situation it would make it easier to answer.

Comment: Since it was 90s music (where dancing on your own is fine), could you add, why you did not _dance_?

Answer (score 6):

As the question is too broad and really depends on what you were hoping to accomplish/what type of person you are, I can only give you what I would have done in this situation. Please keep in mind that this answer will be skewed towards my worldview and my strong points.

1. **Find a group of people to dance with.** The ideal groups are those that are in a loose circle and dancing individually and join in. If you are looking for a partner and are good at dancing it may be advisable to start to dance with one specific person that is already dancing.
2. **Ask someone if they want to dance**, most dance parties have a lot of people that came there to dance, and a fair amount of them will probably in groups of one or two. Do not be afraid to go up and ask someone to dance.
3. **Look for other lonely people.** They may also be by the DJ, or by the refreshments, but look for people that are also alone and strike up a conversation.